# Update to a recent highlight.js for the Wolfram Language

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We've been working hard to update the Mathematica portion of highlight.js, and it [was merged into the main repository](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/2706) some time ago. It fixes all kinds of issues with the old version, e.g. it supports the whole range of Mathematica's crazy way to input numbers:

[image]

If you look at the implementation, you'll find that we use detailed CSS classes that will [default to standard classes](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/mathematica.js#L123-L131). However, it gives the opportunity to adapt the colours specifically for Mathematica in greater detail.

Here is a list of all exposed CSS classes and how they should be coloured:

- `symbol`, `named-character`, `operator`, `brace`: Normal variables and code that should just be coloured black like it is now.
- `builtin-symbol`: The keywords of the language. The blue that's used right now is fine
- `number`: Numbers that should have a dark reddish colour. Probably
- `string`, `message-name`: Should probably have the same colour as numbers. Definitely not green please, because that's what we need for...
- `pattern`, `slot`: special pattern-like expressions that are coloured green in Mathematica and users expect them to be green with the highlighter
- `comment`: The grey that's used right now is fine

**Question:** Can we get an update of the Mathematica highlighter for our site?

Comment: Is there any reason not to add the `feature-request` tag?

Comment: @b3m2a1 The only reason was to give everyone the chance to look at what I've written and possibly add/change details before we ping SE staff.